# Submitting an Infopath form section by section while making previous section uneditable

Tags: sharepoint-2010, conditional-formatting, infopath

I have a InfoPath 2013 form in three sections. When one section is submitted I need the previous one to be become read-only/un-editable. I thought the approach might be to use Views as [detailed here](http://isharepoint2010.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/step-for-creating-form-add-new-field.html) but I need to be able to submit the sections to a list as well as toggle.

I also though that Conditional Formatting might be the approach but when I righ click on the sectors I don't get the option. Any ideas?

[Sections options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh5Og.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can make section's elements disable.

For example, create checkbox chkOne. If Section2 was submitted, change chkOne's value to true. And add Formatting rule for all Section1's controls "If chkOne is true - disable".